# Node Js pipeline sends blank objects to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I try to send data to mongo db from a readable stream, i thought when i use aync on the transform function this would be enough to send the data correctly do mongo db. But instead im sending empty objects. I know its because of async but i dont know where to fix it.

```
const myTransformToJSON = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform(chunk: IData, enc, callback) {
        const jsonChunk = JSON.stringify(chunk)
        callback(null, jsonChunk)
    },
})

async function main() {
    // console.log(MONGODB_ACCESS_KEY)
    const writeToMongoDB = new Transform({
        objectMode: true,
        async transform(chunk: IData, enc, callback) {
            console.log(chunk)
            await ColorModel.create(chunk)
            callback(null)
        },
    })

    await connect(MONGODB_ACCESS_KEY as string)
    const readableStream = fs.createReadStream('./color_srgb.csv')

   async pipeline(
        readableStream,
        csvtojson({ delimiter: ',' }, { objectMode: true }),
        writeToMongoDB,
        // writeAbleStream,
        (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        }
    )
}
```

Could someone help me out?

Within the transformer i send empty objects instead of correct data.